# Adjust vscode interval for sending codelens and codeAction messages

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Right now it seems that `textDocument/codeLens` and `textDocument/codeAction` messages come in a bit too frequently causing perf losses in the LSP extension I work on.

Is there any way to increase the interval at which these messages are being sent to the language server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have seen this problem as well and I implemented the usual approach (a change timer per file) [in my extension](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/extension.ts#L299).

It's pretty simple, e.g. in your extension file (typescript in this case) do something like:

```js
    let changeTimers: Map<string, any> = new Map(); // Keyed by file name.
    workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument((event: TextDocumentChangeEvent) => {
        if (event.contentChanges.length > 0
            && event.document.languageId === "antlr"
            && event.document.uri.scheme === "file") {

            let fileName = event.document.fileName;
            backend.setText(fileName, event.document.getText());
            if (changeTimers.has(fileName)) {
                clearTimeout(changeTimers.get(fileName));
            }
            changeTimers.set(fileName, setTimeout(() => {
                changeTimers.delete(fileName);
                backend.reparse(fileName);
                // ... etc.
            }, 300));
        }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm kinda hoping that there's a config file somewhere rather than handling the message ourselves... but that's looking less likely by the day.